# How can I add the result of a recursive function in a json?

Tags: javascript

I have this json:

```
[
    {
      "question": "1.1",
      "level": 1,
      "id": 4,
      "answers": [
        {
          "text_answer": "NO",
          "questions": [
            {
              "question": "1.1.1",
              "level": 2,
              "id": 3,
              "answers": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "text_answer": null,
          "questions": [
            {
              "question": "1.1.2",
              "level": 2,
              "id": 2,
              "answers": [
                {
                  "text_answer": "SI",
                  "questions": [
                    {
                      "question": "1.1.2.1",
                      "level": 3,
                      "id": 1,
                      "answers": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

this `json` is dynamic and can have `n` amount of levels under the fields `answers`  and `questions` that is why it is necessary to go through them with a `recursive` function

I want to get this output:

```
[
      {
        "question": "1.1",
        "level": 1,
        "id": 4,
        "children": [
          {
            "question": "1.1.1",
            "text_answer": "NO",
            "level": 2,
            "id": 3,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "question": "1.1.2",
            "text_answer": null,
            "level": 2,
            "id": 2,
            "children": [
              {     
                "question": "1.1.2.1",  
                "text_answer": "SI",
                "level": 3,
                "id": 1,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
]
```

the fields `answers`  and `questions` no longer exist, they are renamed `children` and the content of both is unified.

I think this `recursive` function should do a double `foreach`, but I don't know how to do it.

```
function format(d) {
 if (d.respuestas) {
  d.respuestas.forEach((d) => {
    format;
  });
 }
}
format(data);
```

```js
var data=    [
    {
      "question": "1.1",
      "level": 1,
      "id": 4,
      "answers": [
        {
          "text_answer": "NO",
          "questions": [
            {
              "question": "1.1.1",
              "level": 2,
              "id": 3,
              "answers": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "text_answer": null,
          "questions": [
            {
              "question": "1.1.2",
              "level": 2,
              "id": 2,
              "answers": [
                {
                  "text_answer": "SI",
                  "questions": [
                    {
                      "question": "1.1.2.1",
                      "level": 3,
                      "id": 1,
                      "answers": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]


/*     [
      {
        "question": "1.1",
        "level": 1,
        "id": 4,
        "children": [
          {
            "question": "1.1.1",
            "text_answer": "NO",
            "level": 2,
            "id": 3,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "question": "1.1.2",
            "text_answer": null,
            "level": 2,
            "id": 2,
            "children": [
              {     
                "question": "1.1.2.1",  
                "text_answer": "SI",
                "level": 3,
                "id": 1,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
]

   */

function format(d) {
 if (d.answers) {
  d.answers.forEach((d) => {
    format;
  });
 }
}
format(data);

**note:**
I changed the previous structure that I put to the question to make myself understand better.
```

Comment: You aren't calling your recurivse function here in the forEach loop.

Comment: I recommend using probably, Array.reduce.

That is, your format function needs to return the data in the new shape it needs to be, and it needs to get the result and it to your new json object.

Comment: @dwjohnston friend, I do not know much about the subject of `reduce`, but I would like to achieve it with this recursive function, can you help me please? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You have 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 siblings. What question do you expect as your result from the recursive function?  i.e. where would you push your next question to, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3.1.1?  That expectation decides where in "format" function you should put "return" and <if condition> for that return.

Comment: @fluidguid I just search for something like the output json, It is difficult for me and I do not understand, it is like storing the information and modifying the structure as I want in the json.

Comment: How about this <format> function?

https://jsfiddle.net/L6db9kn2/

function format(d) {
      console.log(d);
      if (d.children) {
       return format(d.children[d.children.length - 1]);
     }
     else
     {
      return d;     
     }
    }

The output is json object 1.3.1.1, which is the last question, deepest question, and you can push your next question in your decision tree.  Makes sense?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do here, you don't actually have any formatting logic in your format function.

Comment: @fluidguid I appreciate your effort but I still don't understand how to build my output json

Comment: Can you please change your example jsons to something simplified, and an in english

Comment: @dwjohnston ready, I simplified the json, but I can't simplify the structure more, that's my real problem, I hope you can please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one approach via recurssion. I've commented the code to explain what exactly is going on line by line.

```js
function _process(item) {
  let result = item // we define a copy of item -> result

  // this is renaming the field 'answers' (if found)
  if (item.answers) {
    result.children = item.answers.map(_process) // process each item separately
    delete result.answers
  }

  // if there is a question field, extract the first item in the array and merge the attributes with result
  if (item.questions) {
    result = {
      ...result,
      ..._process(item.questions[0]) // also try to process the item before merging it (to check if there are nested 'questions' or 'answers' fields)
    }
    delete result.questions // remove the questions field
  }

  return result
}

function process(data) {
  return data.map(_process) // start the recurssion for top-level objects
}




// sample data to test out
const data = [{
  "question": "1.1",
  "level": 1,
  "id": 4,
  "answers": [{
      "text_answer": "NO",
      "questions": [{
        "question": "1.1.1",
        "level": 2,
        "id": 3,
        "answers": []
      }]
    },
    {
      "text_answer": null,
      "questions": [{
        "question": "1.1.2",
        "level": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "answers": [{
          "text_answer": "SI",
          "questions": [{
            "question": "1.1.2.1",
            "level": 3,
            "id": 1,
            "answers": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
}]


const result = process(data)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Comment: I think it must be said: your solution is very beautiful. Love it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track in writing a recursive function.

Where I think you're going wrong is in thinking about 'pushing' it to an array or object to store the data.

Instead, what should happen is that your recursive function returns the formatted data, and then that data is added to new json object which is sent back up the call stack.

```js
var data = {
  "name": "1.question",
  "answer": "YES",
  "children": [{
      "name": "1.1 question",
      "answer": "yes"
    },
    {
      "name": "1.2 question",
      "answer": "NO",
      "children": [{
        "name": "1.2.1 question",
        "answer": "NO"
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "1.3 question",
      "answer": "YES",
      "children": [{
        "name": "1.3.1 question",
        "answer": "yes",
        "children": [{
          "name": "1.3.1.1 question",
          "answer": "YES"
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
}



function format(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    // if there are children you are going to recurse deeper
    // use the Array.prototype.map function to _transform_ each of the children. 
    const formattedChildren = d.children.map(v => {
      return format(v);
    });


    // Notice that I'm returning a new object here, as well as 
    // An aggregation of the already transformed data
    return {
      data: "new formatted parent node data goes here",
      children: formattedChildren
    };


  } else { // _always_ have a check for 'is it a leaf node'. 
    // If it's a leaf node node, just format it. 

    //Notice that I'm returning a new object here
    return {
      data: "new formatted leaf node data goes here"
    };
  }
}



console.log(format(data));
```

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, so I've left this blank. But this is the template for how you would recursively traverse and transform a nested object like this.

(Note that you don't need to have a `data` key, I've just put that in as a place holder. It looks like you want `name` and `answered` keys.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to do it this way, but I'm still somewhat tangled in how to convert this to the output structure I need, can you help me with that please? I will thank you in my soul

Comment: So, you want, something like this? It gets the deepest question, adds a new question to it, and then prints the entire decision tree - whole object.  https://jsfiddle.net/yhnz0rmj/
   
    var recursiveResult = format(data);
    recursiveResult.children = [
    {
        "name": recursiveResult.name + " - new question",
        "answer": "YES"
    }
    ];
    console.log(recursiveResult);
    console.log(data);

Comment: I have updated the json, and also added a bounty. Please can you help me, I followed your logic but I have problems

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```js
// here is your JSON
var json = [{
  "question": "1.1",
  "level": 1,
  "id": 4,
  "answers": [{
      "text_answer": "NO",
      "questions": [{
        "question": "1.1.1",
        "level": 2,
        "id": 3,
        "answers": []
      }]
    },
    {
      "text_answer": null,
      "questions": [{
        "question": "1.1.2",
        "level": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "answers": [{
          "text_answer": "SI",
          "questions": [{
            "question": "1.1.2.1",
            "level": 3,
            "id": 1,
            "answers": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
}]

// main
function change(branch) {

  // the first level has a bit different structure
  try {
    if (branch.level == 1) {
      return {
        question: branch.question,
        level:    branch.level,
        id:       branch.id,
        children: change(branch.answers)
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {}

  // next levels
  var new_branch = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < branch.length; i++) {
    new_branch.push({
      question:    branch[i].questions[0].question,
      text_answer: branch[i].text_answer,
      level:       branch[i].questions[0].level,
      id:          branch[i].questions[0].id,
      children:    [change(branch[i].questions[0].answers)].flat(1)
    });
  }
  return new_branch;
}

// output
console.log(JSON.stringify(change(json[0])));
```

Comment: friend, great! it's almost what I need, but I only have one problem. `change(json[0])` the root of my json is an array and can have more than one object with the same structure, so you should use `change(json)`. I hope you can help me because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The trivial solution is to iterate through the array and create a new array: `var json_new = []; for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) { json_new.push(change(json[i])) }`. Something like this. The same can be done via map(): `var json_new = json.map(j => change(j))`.